# Why is connection hanging on 80 or 443?

Tags: ubuntu, php, apache-http-server, vagrant, chef

So I'm using Chef and Vagrant to provision a LAMP stack on a box which I have done before to great success, when along comes this problem. Details as follows:

So netstat says we are good

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2418/apache2
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2418/apache2
```

I can curl to local host when I vagrant ssh into the instance:

```
curl localhost/robots.txt
# This robots.txt file requests that search engines and other...
```

However from outside (my laptop)

```
* Operation timed out
* couldn't connect to host
* Closing connection #0
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

Edit 1: It should be noted that it is not immediate, it actually takes a long time to timeout

My security group on aws is just fine, it's the same one I'm using for an already working machine. The virtualhost file is working in sites-enabled obviously otherwise I wouldn't be able to snag that file from localhost. Nmap says that port 80 and 443 are open, there is nothing in the apache2 logs. I'm almost certain it is something minor I am overlooking. So any insight of any sort would probably be helpful at this point. Thanks in advance.